# Annihilator of annihilator of annihilator of a submodule

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and M be an $R$-module. The question is whether for every submodule $N$ of $M$ the equality

$$\operatorname{Ann}(\operatorname{Ann}(\operatorname{Ann}(N)))=\operatorname{Ann}(N)$$

holds. Anyone can give me a proof or a counter example? Thank you.

Comment: I am sorry. I did typo. The RHS should be Ann(N).

Comment: Now it's just a matter of writing down the definitions. Where are you stuck?

Comment: The RHS \subseteq LHS part is clear. I am stuck in proving LHS \subseteq RHS.

Answer (score 2):

If $\operatorname{Ann}$ means $\operatorname{Ann}_R$, then this is not true in general when $N$ is not an ideal.

For example, take $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $M=N=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Then $\operatorname{Ann}(N)=2\mathbb{Z}$, $\operatorname{Ann}(\operatorname{Ann}(N))=0$, and $\operatorname{Ann}(\operatorname{Ann}(\operatorname{Ann}(N)))=\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

As you've undoubtedly discovered in the other solutions, you need to specify your annihilators more clearly. The expression $\operatorname{Ann}(\operatorname{Ann}(N))$ could be legitimately interpreted as either $\operatorname{Ann}_R(\operatorname{Ann}_R(N))$ or $\operatorname{Ann}_M(\operatorname{Ann}_R(N))$. Jeremy Rickard's example clearly shows the first interpretation leads to disaster, but the second interpretation will work.

Annnihilators furnish an excellent example of ("antitone") [Galois connections](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Galois+connection). Actually all such Galois connections have this property, so we'll be able to simplify notation and get a better result.

Let's denote the poset of submodules of $M$ by $\mathcal{S}$ and the poset of ideals of $R$ by $\mathcal{I}$.

We can define two maps

$F(-)=\operatorname{Ann}_R(-):\mathcal{S}\to \mathcal{I}$ and

$G(-)=\operatorname{Ann}_M(-):\mathcal{I}\to \mathcal{S}$.

1. It is easy to show that if $I\subseteq J$ are ideals of $R$, then $G(J)\subseteq G(I)$, and if $N\subseteq N'$ are submodules of $M$, $F(N')\subseteq F(N)$.
2. Just as easily, you can also show $I\subseteq FG(I)$ and $N\subseteq GF(N)$.

So, $F$ and $G$ create a Galois connection.

> Claim: For a Galois connection using $F$ and $G$, we have both $FGF=F$ and $GFG=G$.

Proof: On one hand, we're assured that $F(N)\subseteq FG(F(N))$ by item 2 above. On the other hand, we know $N\subseteq GF(N)$ by item 2, and then applying $F$ to both sides and reversing order of containment (allowed by item 1) you have $F(N)\supseteq FGF(N)$. Thus $F(N)= FGF(N)$ for all $N$. The proof for $GFG=G$ is virtually identical.

### Conclusion

We can also define a map  $H(-)=\operatorname{Ann}_R:\mathcal I\to\mathcal I$, and $H$ with $H$ does indeed produce a Galois connection on the ideals of $R$. As such,  $HHH=H$, but this is a totally different Galois connection from the $F-G$ one!

As we've seen in this analysis, we can show that $FGF=F$, but there is no expectation of $HHF(N)=F(N)$!